# Let $f$ be a continuous function defined on $[0,1]$ such that $\int_{0}^1f^2(x)dx=\left(\int_{0}^1f(x)dx\right)^2$ Then find range of $f$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f$ be a continuous function defined on $[0,1]$ such that $$\int_{0}^1f^2(x)dx=\left(\int_{0}^1f(x)dx\right)^2$$
Then find range of $f$

I think answer is $0$

Comment: The answer is not 0. For example, if $f$ is a constant, the equality always holds!

Answer (score 2):

Hint : Let $C = \int_{0}^1 f(x)dx$ (of course $C < \infty$). Define $g(x) = f(x) -C$. Then:
$$
\int_{0}^1 g^2(x)dx = \int_0^1 (f(x) - C)^2 dx  \color{blue}{=\ldots = }  0
$$

Fill in the blue part yourself by expanding the square. Now, what can you say about the range of $g$?  (Bigger hint, why is $g$ identically zero?) Finally, what is the range of $f$?

The above can be interpreted (if you know basic probability) as the variance of some random variable being zero. Any random variable with variance zero is constant (a.s., but for our purposes continuity means everywhere), which of course tells us the range of that random variable.